# Add custom XML using C# VSTO addon

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powerpoint, vsto, powerpoint-addins

I am very new to VSTO addon development and C# also. I'm having the below code.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace POC_Powerpoint
{
  public partial class Ribbon1
  {
    private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("POC Running");
        AddCustomXmlPartToPresentation()
    }

    private void AddCustomXmlPartToPresentation(PowerPoint.Presentation presentation)
    {
        string xmlString =
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" +
            "<employees xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/vsto/samples\">" +
                "<employee>" +
                    "<name>Karina Leal</name>" +
                    "<hireDate>1999-04-01</hireDate>" +
                    "<title>Manager</title>" +
                "</employee>" +
            "</employees>";

        Office.CustomXMLPart employeeXMLPart =
            presentation.CustomXMLParts.Add(xmlString, missing);
    }
 }
}
```

Once click the button_1 I want to add some custom xml into presentation. And I don't know how to run this code and how to get the Powerpoint and Office class parts.

I taken those code from [ms-office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-add-custom-xml-parts-to-documents-by-using-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019) docs. Can anyone help me with this? How can I insert the custom XML into the powerpoint file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you are able to click that button, your code won't work anyway, as it is with many MS examples. You have to pass the presentation into `AddCustomXmlPartToPresentation`.

This can be done, by obtaining the ActiveDocument / ActivePresentation from the application instance hosting your addin.

A nice tutorial on putting it together is this one:
[HowTo: Create a Powerpoint AddIn in C#](https://thecolorofcode.com/2019/01/30/howto-create-a-powerpoint-addin-in-c/)

Comment: @jidatevdocs can you explain how can I do this with my code

Comment: From my point of view you could call `AddCustomXmlPartToPresentation` in your click handler like this:
`AddCustomXmlPartToPresentation(Globals.ThisAddin.Application.ActivePresentation)`.

Maybe you would like to check the parameter for null before passing it to the method.